# Is it possible to run simultaneously the OpenVPN server and a Proxy Server on the same VPS?

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn, vps, dante

I have an Ubuntu VPS with OpenVPN server installed, so I connect to it from my home network. Can I install Proxy Server (such as Dante) on the same VPS and connect to it from OpenVPN connection, or do I need additional interface (IP address) for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as both applications use different ports, you can have as many as you need.

You can even say, that VPN will listen on public interface and your proxy only on internal (VPN) address. So there is no port collision at all.

According to the dante documentation (https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.3.x/config/server.html), you can specify port which it will use to listen to (internal: 192.0.2.1 port = 1080). So to answer your quetion - yes you can do it on a single address.